# ListBox deletion

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a listbox, with 2 buttons, new and delete. new adds an item into the list box, and the delete button should delete the item out of the list box. The list box items are tied to a class that stores user entered data from text boxes below.

```
 private void AddListBox()
    {           
        lstCondition.BeginUpdate();
        Condition cond = new Condition("");

        cond.Name = string.Format("Condition {0}", _selection.NetConditions.Count + 1);
        _selection.NetConditions.Add(cond);

        lstCondition.EndUpdate();

        lstCondition.SelectedItem = cond;                     

        cboNetCondition.Properties.Items.Clear();
        cboNetCondition.Properties.Items.AddRange(NetCondition);
        cboControlType.Properties.Items.Clear();
        cboControlType.Properties.Items.AddRange(ControlType);
        cboFlowRate.Properties.Items.Clear();
        cboFlowRate.Properties.Items.AddRange(FlowRate);
    }

 private void btnNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AddListBox();

        }
```

the cbo items are comboboxes, whose data gets tied in the condition class to each instance of the list box.

```
 public frmNetConditions(Condition condo, Selection selection)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _selection = selection;
        lstCondition.DataSource = _selection.NetConditions;
        condition = _selection.NetConditions.Count;

    }

 private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        selectedCondition = (Condition)lstCondition.SelectedItem;

        cboControlType.SelectedIndex = -1;
        cboNetCondition.SelectedIndex = -1;
        cboFlowRate.SelectedIndex = -1;
        txtFlowRate.Text = string.Empty;
        txtStatPressure.Text = string.Empty;
        txtDampOpening.Text = string.Empty;
        txtDensity.Text = string.Empty;
        cboDensity.SelectedIndex = -1;

        lstCondition.Items.Remove(lstCondition.SelectedItem);
        lstCondition.Refresh();


    }
```

After pressing this delete button, the listbox, still contains the item i wish to delete, im unsure why thats the case?

Update with datasource

```
 public List<Condition> NetConditions { get { return _netconditions; } }
```

Comment: Can you post your entire code related to your Listbox?

Comment: Do you bind your list to a List<T> or something similar?

Comment: `lstCondition` does not seem to get populated, but you try to assign its SelectedItem.

Comment: lstCondition is the listbox let me edit

Comment: the selected item being which item the user has highlighted at the moment.

Comment: You should be getting an error.  You can't remove an item from the ListBox items collection when it's using a DataSource.  You would have to remove it from the DataSource.  What is your DataSource? If List<T>, use a BindingList<T> instead.

Comment: @LarsTech updated with datasource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already suggested, you should bind to a `BindingList<Condition>` instead of a `List<Condition>`. This allows you to change the datasource and the control (`ListBox`) to get notified by your changes. The code should look like this:

```
lstCondition.ValueMember = "ConditionId";
lstCondition.DisplayMember = "Name";
lstCondition.DataSource = NetConditions;
```

After defining the binding, the correct way of operating on the `ListBox` items is to remove from the `datasource`, not the `ListBox` itself:

```
// SelectedItem should be checked for null (no selection is an option)
NetCondition.Remove((Condition)lstCondition.SelectedItem);
```

However, if you plan to change properties from an element (so, not the list itself), the control is notified only if your element (Condition) implements [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) interface.

Comment: okay so its impossible to do, while its a list, and not a binding list

Comment: I think it is the most convenient way to do it. [BindingList<T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679(v=vs.110).aspx) is just an enhanced generic list to be used in binding scenarios as you have here.